# Adding size restrictions to files to the file properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

When I add `properties.yml` https://pastebin.com/yRAGSTzf to my file configuration at the end of my file

```
spring:
  http:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 100MB
      max-request-size: 200MB
```

during compilation, he throws me away

```
    ...
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserException: while parsing MappingNode
 in 'reader', line 2, column 1:
    spring.datasource:
    ^
Duplicate key: spring
 in 'reader', line 74, column 1:

    ^
```

Comment: show full yaml. the error looks like something else

Comment: But at pastebin, I gave the whole code of this file.

Comment: your yaml is completely wrong. see how to create yml files

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are adding the same key ('spring') twice. Did you try to repeat the last 5 lines?